# Error al tranferir data de usando nodejs router y socket.io

Tags: nodejs, typescript, socket.io

Estoy trabajando en el bakcend de un una app web y es la primera vez que hago uso de socket.io en nodejs. Pero al intentar hacer un emit de la data que recibo en el controlado de las rutas recibo el siguiente error:  TypeError: req.app.get(...).emit is not a function

**Sockets.ts**

```
function socket( io ){
    io.on("connection", socket => {
        var socketId = socket.id;
        var clientIp = socket.request.connection.remoteAddress;
        console.log('New connection ' + socketId + ' from ' + clientIp);
        
        socket.on("disconnect", () => {
          console.log("Client disconnected");
        });
      
      });
}

export default socket;
```

El error se produce en el controlador de las rutas al tratar de utilizar el emit.

**router.controller.ts**

```
export const getData: RequestHandler = async (req, res) => {

  
  const options= {
    method: 'GET',
  };

  const response = await fetch(citybikeurl, options)
    .then((res: any) => res.json())  
    .catch((e: any) => {
      console.error({ error: e });
    });
  
  req.app.get('io').emit(res.json(response))
 
  
}
```

**routes.ts**

```
router.get('/', dataController.getData)
```

Aquí está definido el uso del socket.

**app.ts**

```
app.set('io', io)
```

Hasta el momento no sé si estoy pasando algún dato debido al error que está presentando.